how do I configure a network to give different MAC addresses depending on the IP address?
I have two virtual bridges, one (vmbr0) with a primary and secondary IP address and another (vmbr1) with an internal network. vmbr1 is set up with masquerade so that the MAC address for vmbr0 is used, not the MAC addresses of the internal network's devices. I want to set up the network so that the MAC address of vmbr0 changes because my hosting provider requires using a specific MAC address for the secondary IP

Please note that "MAC" is not "MAC Address". I have corrected your tags for you.

Some devices allow MAC address spoofing. What Virtualization platform are you using? This will likely determine what you can and cannot do. Can you just ask the hosting provider to update the MAC address they issue the IP address to, or is this an attempt to circumvent some limit or controls on their end?

I'm using Proxmox. I just want to match what I have with them. they send nasty emails if the MAC addresses don't even match


vmbr1 is set up with masquerade so that the MAC address for vmbr0 is used, not the MAC addresses of the internal network's devices.

That makes pretty much no sense. the MAC address for vmbr0 is used as long as the VM host acts as a router and traffics are L3-forwarded out via vmbr0. It does not matter if you set up source NAT / IP masquerade for the internal network.

because my hosting provider requires using a specific MAC address for the secondary IP

The real problem here is that it seems that you want to use the secondary IP for traffics from the internal network (and this MAC address requirement from the provider).
Things should be easy if only the secondary IP has this MAC address requirement -- you just set MAC address of vmbr0 to this specific MAC address. Since both IP addresses are assigned to the same interface (vmbr0), it should be sufficient to just use the SNAT target of iptables (which allows an IP address to be specified) instead of the MASQUERADE target (which AFAIK picks the first / primary address of the route interface).
My guess is that both IP addresses have MAC address requirement, and that this stupid provider even requires a one-to-one mapping (meaning that you can't submit the same MAC address for both IP addresses)? If that's the case, things are trickier, because it pretty much means that you'll need separate interfaces for the two IP addresses, at least two "logical" ones. (I am not aware of any other way. Like even while you can rewrite the the source MAC address of certain frames with nftables. You probably can't "intercept" frames with the destination MAC address.)
And there goes MACVLANs. You can probably get rid of vmbr0 and have two MACVLANs attached to the (v)NIC that was enslaved to the bridge, then use one for each IP address. (EDIT: but then, why aren't you using/offered different vNIC for diffrent IP?) Make sure you set the arp_ignore sysctl to 1, btw.
There are a few problems though. For one if you actually need a "bridged/external bridge", now it means that you'll need to enslave a MACVLAN to the bridge. In my experience, things could get a bit fragile with setup like this, but it's not like it's something impossible, AFAIK. (However, given the MAC address requirement, I don't see how you'd want a "bridged/external bridge" anyway.)
The bigger problem is that now you probably need to set up policy routing (i.e., ip rules, alternate route tables) for the internal network. Source NAT / IP masquerade occurs after route decision. It means that when you have multiple (logical) interfaces, you can't just use the SNAT target to pick one to use. If you try that, you'll probably bump into the same problem. (Well, slightly different, the communication will probably become "asymmetric" interface / MAC address-wise. If your provider checks only the ARP responses, you might get away with such quirky setup, assuming it won't cause problem in any other aspect.)

I'm using Hetzner if it helps

@evalprime I have no experience with VPS providers. You probably want to ask them yourself on what exactly these MAC requirements are. (Well maybe someone else will pop up here and give you a vendor-specific answer.) If for whatever reasons they offer you two IPs but only one link and/or vNIC, I don't suppose you actually need to use different MACs addresses for them. Chances are what you really need to do is just set the MAC address of vmbr0 to the given MAC address of the vNIC (and change the MAC address of the vNIC to a some random one; that is, just swap their MAC addresses, basically)

I did what you suggested but now the VMs on the secondary IP can't connect

@evalprime You'll need to add outputs of ip a, iptables-save and nft list ruleset from the proxmox to your post. (You may redact public IP addresses and MAC addresses in the output, but make sure you make it clear which is which.)
